# Union Set and Correspondence In $R_{+}^{2}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have these sets: $q = [0,1]$ and $Z=\{1,2\}$, Let $\mathbb{Y}$ be the set combination $(q,z)$ .

Let Y and Y' elements of $\mathbb{Y}$.  $Y = [0,1] \times \{1\} \cup \{(0,2)\}$ and $Y' = [0,1]  \times \{2\} \cup \{(0,1)\}$

My questions:

1) Y is a vertical line on 1? And Y' is a vertical line on 2?

2) It is clear that there is no relation such $\subseteq$ or $\supseteq$ between $Y'$ and $Y$. Right?

3) What Is the joint set: $Y \cup Y'$ and the intersection set: $Y \cap Y'$?

What I did:

1) I believe it is right that there is no relation $\cup$ or $\cap$ between $Y'$ and $Y$.

2) This what I did:

$Y \cup Y' = [0,1] \cup \{1,2\}$ It would be a vertical line on 1 and a vertical lie on 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, there are a few things that don't quite make sense about your post, but I think I can tell what you're getting at. It seems that you mean the following:

- $Q$ is the real interval from $0$ to $1,$ inclusive.
- $Z$ is the set whose elements are just $1$ and $2.$
- $\Bbb Y=Q\times Z.$

Now, it looks like we have that

- $Y$ is the set comprised of the ordered pair $\langle 0,2\rangle$ together with the elements of $Q\times\{1\}.$
- $Y'$ is the set comprised of the ordered pair $\langle 0,1\rangle$ together with the elements of $Q\times\{2\}.$

If I'm correct about what you mean by $\Bbb Y,$ this would make $Y$ and $Y'$ *subsets* of $\Bbb Y,$ rather than elements of $\Bbb Y.$ I can't think of an interpretation of $\Bbb Y$ that would make $Y$ and $Y'$ elements of it, but there may be something I'm missing.

So, we could think of $Y$ as a vertical segment on $1,$ together with a single point off that segment. We can think of $Y'$ similarly. It's quite correct that $Y\not\subseteq Y'$ and $Y\not\supseteq Y'.$ $Y\cup Y'$ *would* consist of a vertical segment on both $1$ and $2.$ Moreover, if I'm correct about what you mean by $\Bbb Y,$ we in fact have that $Y\cup Y'=\Bbb Y.$

Comment: thanks for you effort in understand my question You are right about the $Q$, $Z$ and$ \mathbb{Y}$ sets. And what about the intersection? I think it is: $\{(0,1), (0,2)\}$. Only two points. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, indeed! Nicely done, Laura.